# Getting Null Value when passing variables from controller to model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having some problem. I am trying to pass a variable from a controller to a model, but I always get a NULL value ON THE MODEL. Anyone can point out what is wrong with my code?

CONTROLLER

```
public function test()
{
    $this->load->model('model_register');

    //ID Creation to be inserted into the database
    $country_prefix = $this->model_register->countryprefix();
    $org_prefix = $this->model_register->organizationprefix();
    $insertion = $this->model_register->insertion();

    $userid_base = $country_prefix['0']['c_code'].$org_prefix['0']['id'];

    $basenum = "000000000";
    $base_length = strlen($basenum);
    $id_length = strlen($org_prefix['0']['id']);

    $computation = $base_length - $id_length;

    $id_base_array = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $computation; $i++)
    {
        array_push($id_base_array, "0");
    }

    $id_base = implode("",$id_base_array);

    $userid_admin = $country_prefix['0']['c_code']."ADM".$id_base.$org_prefix['0']['id'];

    //Insert Data

    //data-mix
    $data['userid'] = $userid_base;
    $data['baselength'] = strlen($basenum);
    $data['id_length'] = strlen($org_prefix['0']['id']);
    $data['result'] = $computation;
    $data['id_base'] = implode("",$id_base_array);
    $data['userid_admin'] = $userid_admin;
    $data['insertion'] = $insertion;

    $insertion = $this->model_register->insertion($data['userid_admin']);

}
```

Model

```
public function insertion($x)
{
    $value = $x;

    $data = array(
        'testid' => $value,
    );

    $this->db->insert('test',$data);

    return $value;
}
```

When I run this, I get

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`testid`) VALUES (NULL)
```

Comment: need to pass `$x` form controller `$this->model_register->insertion();`

Comment: you have called **insertion()** two times at first time you are passing nothing. checkout this in your code `$insertion = $this->model_register->insertion();`  so at that time it will through a error.

Comment: I tried something and it seems to be getting there.First I declared this on the controller, $insertion = $this->model_register->insertion($data); 

Then on my model I have this. $value = $x['userid_admin'];

When I print_r($value); The value I am passing on shows, but on the $data array, it is still null.

Comment: Did what @RajJagani write not work?

Comment: I omitted the double insertion() call. Thanks @RajJagani! This solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called insertion twice with two different 'arguments'. The first one `$insertion = $this->model_register->insertion();` was called without parameters and the second was called with parameters, `$insertion = $this->model_register->insertion($data['userid_admin']);`

This condition may fall under [Method Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php), a condition where the same method is created but with different parameters and as such can perform two different functionalities.

If you want to use the same function in both cases, however the best fix is to pass a default `NULL` value as the parameter in the Model file, like this

```
public function insertion($x = NULL) {
    // Function code appears here
}
```